# Using Hibernate with MS SQL and domain user

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jdbc

Good morning,

I'm trying to connect to an MS SQL Server with Hibernate 4.3. Connecting with SSO and database credentials (username and password) works fine, but when I try to use a username with a domain (domain\user) specification, I get the following exception.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
caused by com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverexception login failed for user
```

- The username and password are valid (already checked).
- Tryed it with \\ at the input and replaced it with \ in the jdbc-string
- Tryed to set the properties with

  ```
  ((org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration) configuration)
  .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "domain\user");
  ```
- Tryed to set the properties over the jdbc connection string

  ```
  jdbc:sqlserver://[IP]:[PORT];user=[domain\user];password=[pwd];databaseName=[db]
  ```
- Tryed to encapsulate with \' and \" around the user and password.

It would be glad, if somebody can suggest how to get this work.

If some Informations are required, I will extend this post if requested.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

The [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558122%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) mentioned by Mark Rotteveel mentioned the missing piece.

> To continue using integrated authentication with sqljdbc_auth.dll, just specify **integratedSecurity=true**
>
> connection property (and optionally 
>   **authenticationScheme=NativeAuthentication**).
>
> don't forget to specify the **domain=[DOMAIN];** part

Specially the part of set the authenticationScheme was missing in the connection String. Without that, the SSO was used.

Now the jdbc connection string for the domain-users looks like:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[IP]:[PORT];IntegratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=NativeAuthentication;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;selectMethod=cursor;domain=[DOMAIN];user=[DOMAIN\USER];password=[PW];databaseName=[DB];
```

Thanks for the replys and have a nice day.

PS:
I didn't tested the possible solution with JDNI, which is suggested by BharatG. But thank you.

Comment: As far as I know if you want to use a domain user, then you need to use kerberos or active directory authentication (ie integratedSecurity=true and the necessary DLL on the library path, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.110%29.aspx#Connectingintegrated and for Kerberos: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558122%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Comment: the second link gav eme the missing piece, thank you. If you transform it into an answere, I will rate it and be able to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try if one of the following works?

1) Place the connection properties as the JNDI settings

2) Escaping the username as "domain\\user" (not sure if this is what you
   tried in your 2nd bullet)

Comment: your 2nd point was the same as I tried to mentioned, but the editor of stackoverflow needs a escape character for \\\ - I didnt recognized it until you mentioned that. I didnt tested the first suggestion, because Marks worked for me, but thank you.